# Update elasticsearch settings via Tire

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

Is it possible to use Tire to update elasticsearch settings?  I have this curl command I'd like to run automatically.

```
`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tweets/_settings -d '{
      "index" : {
          "refresh_interval" : "-1"
      }
  }'`
```

The value is available via tire but I'm not sure how to apply it.

```
Tweet.tire.settings[:refresh_interval]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, but ugly :)

```
Tire::Configuration.client.put([Tire::Configuration.url, Tweet.index.name].join('/'),
                               index: { refresh_interval: '-1' })
```

Will get nicer in future versions...

Comment: Thanks.  If you want to give me your ideas around adding this feature to the gem I'd be happy to give it a shot.